# How to use multiple providers for a single store in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a single store that manages state for two components `A` and `B`.

I wrap each of the components in a provider like such, and these are rendered through sdk tools from my company which I cannot change, hence the reason I am using two providers:

### A.js

```
import { store } from './store';

<Provider store={store}>
  <A />
</Provider>
```

### B.js

```
import { store } from './store';

<Provider store={store}>
  <B />
</Provider>
```

### store.js

```
export const store = createStore(combineReducers(mainReducer, AReducer, BReducer));
```

I set up the action to dispatch another action handled by `B`'s reducer, so that these two components can share the state. However, when I perform the action in `A` component, the reducer works fine for `A`, but it doesn't fire off for `B`. Is there a way to make this work using two sibling provider components?

Comment: The idea behind Redux state management is to have a single source of truth, which is the store, for the entire application; why are you using two different providers for two different components, rather than a single provider for the entire application?

Comment: What would be the use-case for two providers? If both subtrees share the same application state I don't see any reason to not put them into the same provider.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am constrained to using two providers as I am rendering these components through sdk tools from my company.

Answer (score 1):

The structure for a react-redux app is to have a main App.js where you handle your routing, loading of components etc. Then in your index.js you import and render the App.

If you follow this structure then all you need to do is to wrap App with the redux provider. Your index.js would then look something like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store()}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Now all that is left is to import your components to App.js and use them as needed.

**Edit**: It is possible but I still think you get confused about how to setup the import of your components in one application. Anyway, you can try the following approach:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import Component1 from "./component1";
import Component2 from "./component2";
import store from "./redux/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  [
    <Provider store={store} key="1">
      <Component1 />
    </Provider>,
    <Provider store={store} key="2">
      <Component2 />
    </Provider>
  ],
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

You may find a working code sandbox here [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-tesla-03dkq?file=/src/index.js:0-450)

Comment: @dylanpark I've updated my answer with a working example of two providers. I hope this is what you wanted.